# Matlab-Transfer Function to Difference Equation

Tags: matlab, function, equation, transfer, difference

Is there any function in matlab software which transform a transfer function to one difference equation?

Comment: You can use ```[num,den] = tfdata(sys)``` to get numerator and denominator coefficients of a transfer function. Is that enough?

Comment: Thank you for your response.No,i want an equation of this form:
mx''(t)+kx'(t)+x(t)+n=f(t) directly from tranfer function.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21054-can-matlab-give-me-difference-equation-from-transfer-fucntion

Comment: Thank you.Will it work for a continuous time system?

Comment: @dimig Difference Equations are by definition discrete.  for a continuous system you'd need an inverse laplace (trivial for transfer functions), or you could use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46034-inverse-laplace-transform-of-transfer-function-class)